# How to disable post unicode character using php

Tags: php, emoji

I have a question about how to send unicode character from database. I see newly i can not send unicode

For example when i try to send `&#x26a0;` then it is showing empty post from database. What is the problem here anyone can tell me please ?

```
<textarea name="text">&#x26a0;</textarea>`

if(isset($_POST['text'])){ 
    $textPost = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['text']);
    $saveText = mysqli_query($db,
        "INSERT INTO posts(text) VALUES($textPost)") 
        or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
}
```

Comment: If you are looking at the contents of the table from a console, it could be that the symbol is being stored as the symbol itself and the symbol doesn't exist within the character table of the console. Have you tried dumping the table onto a webpage?

Comment: try putting Values('$textPost')

Comment: @Hive7 From database table i see empty post. There is nothing. The character is emoji character you can try it in textare. `&#x26a0;` = &#x26a0; php code is not saving it from database table.

Comment: change the database from utf8 or whatever to utf8mb4

Comment: Values stores into database properly ?

Comment: Why don't you use utf8_encode() before inserting into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use utf8_encode() while inserting data into db. For example you have `'<textarea name="text">⚠</textarea>'`

You can use:

```
$_POST['text'] = '<textarea name="text">⚠</textarea>';
$textPost = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, utf8_encode( $_POST['text'] ) );
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts(text) VALUES($textPost)";
$saveText = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

And while getting from database you can use utf8_decode() to decode utf8 characters.